# Java: How to store MediumBlob in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob

I'm trying to store MediumBlob data in MySQL using java. But I have no success to retrieve the data.

To store I'm using:

```
PreparedStatement = stmt conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE INTO table VALUE(?)");
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
stmt.setBinaryStream(position, bais, data.length);
```

Is there correcty?

Comment: Does it get into the database correctly?  When you say you have no success retrieving the data what do you mean?

Comment: have you tried [setBlob()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of setbinaryStream() ?

Comment: Using setBlob() a exception occurs when I call stmt.update()

Comment: @jzd some data is returned by the databse, but is not the data that I have on setBinaryData. Is something different... :(

Comment: @Victor, what is the exception you are getting with setBlob()?

Comment: Now I'm using setClob, but setBlob was returning the same error: 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setClob(ILjava/io/Reader;)V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it!!!!

The problem was when I was retrieving the data. I was calling:

```
ResultSet.getClob
```

But I should call:

```
ResultSet.getBinaryStream
```

I have used setBinaryStream to input data!

This was confusing because I have a Clob field, and I was expecting retrieving a Clob field in Java code!